# Why can't $\int_1^3 \frac{4}{(2x-3)^4} dx $ be evaluated by calculators or WolframAlpha?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is the integral
$$\int_1^3 \frac{4}{(2x-3)^4} dx $$

Solving by u-substitution, it works fine.
$$ \text{let}~~ u = 2x-3 $$

$$\int_1^34 \cdot  ( 2x-3 )^{-4}dx $$

$$\ x = \frac{u+3}{2} $$

$$\ \frac{ dx }{ du }=\frac{1 }{2} $$
$$\ dx = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }du $$

EDIT:
$$\ u(3) = 2(3)- 3$$
$$\ u(3) = 3 $$
$$\ u(1) = 2(1)- 3$$
$$\ u(1) = -1 $$
$$\int_{-1}^3 4 \cdot  u^-4 \cdot \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }du $$

$$\int_{-1}^3 2\cdot u^{-4}du $$

$$\frac{ 2u^{-3}}{-3 } \Bigg \vert_{-1}^{3} \ $$

$$ = \frac{ 2}{-3(2x-3)^3 } \Bigg \vert_{-1}^{3} \ $$

$$ = \frac{  2}{ -3(2(3)-3)^3 } -  \frac{  2}{ -3(2(-1)-3)^3} $$
$$ = \frac{-2}{81} - \frac{2}{375} $$
$$ = \frac{-84}{125} $$

But plugging this integral into a TI-84 CE Plus throws an error "Cannot divide by 0"

Also trying online calculators,
[Wolframalpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4C57.png) and [Freemathhelp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtBuK.png), the problem is unable to be solved.

Why can't this problem be solved on these calculators?

Comment: It's an improper integral (the function is not defined for $$x=3/2$$) and the improper integral does not converge

Comment: A simpler example of this wrong reasoning is $\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1{x^2}dx = (-\frac 1x) |_{-1}^1 = -2$. – Note also that the result cannot be correct because the integral over a positive function can not be negative.

Comment: I don't understand why this has downvotes. It has a clear attempt.

Comment: Note that you made in mistake in the substitution, namely the bounds are wrong. The new interval is $[-1,3]$ not $[1,3]$. And $\dfrac 2{u^4}$ is not defined in $0\in[-1,3]$ and your integral is still improper after substitution.

Comment: @zwim Why does the interval change to $$\ [-1,3] $$

Comment: The interval changes due to your substitution. @Oreofe

Comment: You have $u(x)=2x-3$ so the bounds $u(1)=-1$ and $u(3)=3$. When you do u-subs, the bounds must be changed to $\displaystyle\int_{u(1)}^{u(3)} f(u)du$

Comment: @zwim the interval change still does explain why the integral cannot be solved on calculators.

Comment: The integral doesn't make sense because of the singularity at $x = 3/2.$ Sure, you can use a u-sub, but does the integral make sense? No. That's why calculators can't do it because they're approximating something that looks like, say, $\frac{1}{10^{-32}}.$

Comment: Also, ask yourself - how does a positive function have negative area?

Comment: At first I thought your problem was using an inferior TI calculator.  My HP Prime returned infinity on this one.  Running the numerical integrator on my WP-34s did not converge; last time I looked it was around 6,201,000,000, which is mathematically defined as "almost infinity".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP: *the interval change still does explain why the integral cannot be solved on calculators*

This is because the "dysfunction"/discrepancy that you are raising has nothing to do with the integration-by-substitution process.

**If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$** and has antiderivative $F,$ the [second fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) guarantees that $$\int_a^b f=F(b)-F(a).$$ In your example, the boldfaced condition is not satisfied (the integral fails to converge/exist due to the singularity at $x=1.5$), and $$\int_1^3 \frac{4}{(2x-3)^4} \mathrm dx\ne \left[\frac2{3 (3 - 2 x)^3}\right]_1^3,$$ even though $$\int\frac{4}{(2x-3)^4} \mathrm dx=\frac2{3 (3 - 2 x)^3}+C.$$

This, together with Martin's example in the second comment, shows that an integrand may have an antiderivative whilst not being integrable on the desired interval.

Answer (score 6):

When we reason$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=[F(x)]_a^b=F(b)-F(a),$$we assume every $g$ with $g^\prime=f$ satisfies $g(b)-g(a)=F(b)-F(a)$, so the choice of $f$'s antiderivative is irrelevant.

But in general, antiderivatives differ additively by *locally* constant functions on the integrand's domain, which due the discontinuity at $x=\frac32$ is in this case in two components as $[1,\,3]\setminus\left\{\frac32\right\}=\left[1,\,\frac32\right)\cup\left(\frac32,\,4\right]$. We can [make this even more technical](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218109), but that's all we need for now.

A locally constant function on this domain can have different values either side of $\frac32$, say $C_-$ on the left and $C_+$ on the right. But if we add such a function to an antiderivative of $4(2x-3)^{-4}$, the difference between the antiderivatives' values at $a,\,b$ with $a<\frac32<b$ changes by $C_+-C_-$, which is in general nonzero, and so the integral is improper.