# Negative number in logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, logarithms

I was given a problem to evaluate the following integral,
$$\int\limits_{-4}^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$$

I know the fact that integration of $1/x$ is $\log(x)$ but how can we compute negative logarithm? I mean to say that since definite integral refers to the area under the curve so how can it be even defined?

I tried the following method:
$$\int\limits_{-4}^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}dx = \log(-1) - \log(-4)$$
$$\implies \log\left(\dfrac{-1}{-4}\right) = -\log(4)$$

Is it correct? I don't think that the answer should be $-\log(4)$ because there is no graph for the negative logarithm. Is there any need of complex logarithm?

Comment: Nope. The indefinite integral (antiderivative) of $\frac{1}{x}$ (on any interval not containing $0$) is $\log(|x|)+C$, not $\log(x)+C$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, I didn't know that, I'm just a newcomer to integrals. Thanks for the help! :))

Comment: Make the substitution $ t= -x $.

Comment: Check it out. If $f(x)=\log(-x)$ on $x<0$, then $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{1}{-x}\cdot (-1)$ (chain rule) $=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: In fact, the $C$ in @StinkingBishop's comment [can take different values either side of $x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218109), so your definite integral is only well-defined because $0$ isn't between its limits. We say $C$ is _locally constant_.

Comment: $\int\limits_{-4}^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x}dx =- \int\limits_{1}^{4}\dfrac{1}{y}dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative logarithms *do* exist, just not in the real numbers.  The complex log function yields the same value as the log function, but on negative numbers it adds a complex component, but which is constant!

As a commenter noted, most books put the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ as $\ln(|x|)$ to prevent going outside the domain.  However, if you allow for complex functions, $\ln(x)$ actually still works.  In fact, they are equivalent, if you allow $C$ to be complex, and allow for the fact that you probably shouldn't integrate across the non-smooth point at $x = 0$ (thus you may have different constants of integration).

For instance, for the natural logarithm, logarithms of negative numbers get $i\,\pi$ added to their positive equivalent.  Therefore, if, between 0 (the non-smooth point) and $-\infty$, the constant of integration included $-i\,\pi$, then the two definitions would give you the same result.

Comment: What is a “complex component”?