# Integrate $2u/(u-u^3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I'm currently trying to integrate:
$$
\int \! \frac{2u}{u-u^3} \, du = \ln \frac{u+1}{u-1} + \ln C
$$

I've tried to use partial fractions to simplify the
$$
\frac{1}{u-u^3} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{2 \ln{(1+u)}} + \frac{1}{2 \ln{(1-u)}}
$$
and then do integration by parts, but it doesn't look like quite right.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: factorise $u-u^3$ to $u(1-u)(1+u)$ and solve from there

Comment: What did you do with the numerator? Please show your work so far.

Comment: @Joh
I did integration by parts using:
- the partial fraction expression from 1/(u-u^3)
-and the 2u

The partial fraction of 1/(u-u^3) gave me 1/u -1/2(1+u) +1/2(1-u).
However, when integrating by parts with this and 2u,
a = 2u ; b = partial fraction expression
a' = u^2 /2 ; b = ln(u) - ln(1+u)/2 - ln(1-u)/2 
and subbing this into the formula for integration by parts does not seem like it would give the answer.

Comment: Can you simplify the fraction before doing partial fractions?

Comment: You do not need integration by parts. This should be done exclusively by partial fraction decomposition. You have to know how to deal with each type of partial fraction.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales - Well i did try at one point to do partial fractions on the whole expression of 2u/(u-u^3), using fractions of a/u + b/(1-u) and c/(1+u), where a, b and c are constants. but this gave me a = 0. Is my partial fraction form incorrect?

Comment: @Almond How could a partial fraction decomposition of a rational function involve logarithms? The very first observation you should make is that $\frac{{2u}}{{u - u^3 }} = \frac{2}{{1 - u^2 }}$.

Comment: @Gary -- thank you this was my issue. I don't know why I didn't notice that earlier!

Comment: You should include your calculations, that way we could see where you made a mistake.

Comment: Note the $C$ in $\int\frac{2du}{1-u^2}=\ln\left|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right|+C$ is a locally constant function which can have different values on each of $(-\infty,\,-1),\,(-1,\,1),\,(1,\,\infty)$. It's a more complicated variant of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218109).

Answer (score 3):

You have :
\begin{align}
\frac{2u}{u-u^3} &=\frac{2u}{u(1-u^2)}\\ &=\frac{2}{(1+u)(1-u)}\\ &= \frac{2+u-u}{(1+u)(1-u)} \\ &=\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\\&=\frac{1}{1+u}-\frac{1}{u-1} \end{align}
When we integrate :
$$\int \frac{2u}{u-u^3} \mathrm{d}u = \int \frac{1}{1+u}-\frac{1}{u-1} \mathrm{d}u = \ln\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the indefinite integral $\int \dfrac{2u}{u-u^{3}}du$:

1. Factorize the denominator
   $$
   \int{\dfrac{2u}{u(1-u)(1+u)}}du
   $$
2. Assume
   $$
   \dfrac{2u}{u(1-u)(1+u)} = \dfrac{P}{u} + \dfrac{Q}{1-u}+ \dfrac{R}{1+u}
   $$
3. Evaluate $P,Q,\text{ and }R$
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \dfrac{2u}{u(1-u)(1+u)} &= \dfrac{P}{u} + \dfrac{Q}{1-u}+ \dfrac{R}{1+u}\\
   &=\dfrac{P(1-u)(1+u)+Q(u)(1+u)+R(u)(1-u)}{u(1-u)(1+u)}\\
   &=\dfrac{u^{2}(Q-P-R)+u(Q+R)+P}{u(1-u)(1+u)}\\
   \implies Q-P-R &= 0\\
   Q+R &= 2\\
   P &= 0\\
   \implies P,Q,R = 0,1,1
   \end{align}
   $$
4. Substitute the values of $P,Q,\text{ and },R$
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \dfrac{2u}{u(1-u)(1+u)} &= \dfrac{0}{u} + \dfrac{1}{1-u}+ \dfrac{1}{1+u}\\
   &= \dfrac{1}{1-u}+ \dfrac{1}{1+u}
   \end{align}
   $$
5. Evaluate the integral using $\int{\dfrac{1}{a+bx}dx}=\dfrac{1}{b}\ln{(a+bx)} + C $
   $$
   \begin{align}
   &\int{\dfrac{2u}{u(1-u)(1+u)}}du\\
   &=\int{\left[ \dfrac{1}{1-u}+\dfrac{1}{1+u} \right]}du\\
   &=\int{\dfrac{1}{1-u}}du + \int{\dfrac{1}{1+u}}du\\
   &=-\ln{(1-u)} + \ln{(1+u)} + C\\
   &=\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+u}{1-u}\right)}+C
   \end{align}
   $$