# Simplifying negative ln

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Could someone explain to me why the negative part in the second term switches

$\ln (1+x) - \ln (1-x)$ becomes $\ln \frac{1+x}{x-1}$.

I understand the division just not why $-x$ becomes $+x$ and the $+1$ becomes $-1$.

Many thanks.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\ln(\frac{1+x}{x-1})$ on the right, it's not true. Try $x = 0$, for instance.

Comment: What's the context in which this came up?

Comment: Do you mean $\ln|1+x|-\ln|1-x|=\ln\left|\frac{1+x}{x-1}\right|$? If so, I'm guessing you forgot the mod signs when a logarithm comes out of integration. (Before anyone else mentions it, [there's one further subtlety](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218109) to such integration on $\Bbb R$.)