# Why is this complex integral $-\frac{i\pi}{3}$ and not $0$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am stuck on a complex integration problem and any help is appreciated!

> **Question.** Integrate
>
> $$ \int_{C[0,3]} \frac{dz}{z^2-2z-8} .$$

I used partial fraction decomposition to get this to be

$$ \int_{C[0,3]} \frac{1}{6(z-4)} \, dz - \int_{C[0,3]}\frac{1}{6(z+2)} \, dz .$$

The first summand is $0$ since the circle $C[0,3]$ is contractible on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-2,4\}$.

To evaluate the second summand I parametrized the circle with $\gamma(t)=3e^{it}$ where $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Then I get that the complex integral is

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{3ie^{it}}{6(3e^{it}+2)} \, dt .$$

Now here is where the confusion arrives.

I believe that the antiderivative is $\frac{1}{6}\ln|3e^{it}+2|$. Evaluating this at 0 or $2\pi$ gives $\frac{1}{6}\ln(5)$ in both cases so the definite integral would be $0$.

However the solutions at the back of the book say the correct answer is $-\frac{i\pi}{3}$ and Wolfram Alpha confirms this but does not give the steps.

I don't understand how it's possible that the indefinite integral is the same at the boundary points but the definite integral is not $0$? Any explanation is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming $C[0,3]$ is a circle centred at $0$ with radius $3$? Are you familiar with Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: Of course, by the same argument $\int_{C[0,1]}\frac1z\,\mathrm dz=0$, right? But it's equal to $2\pi i$. It turns out that the function that you are integrating has no antiderivative. In particular, $\frac{\ln|3e^{it}+2|}6$ is not an antiderivative of your function.

Comment: Yes we just covered Cauchy's integral formula but the next problem says to solve the same integral using this method so I'm assuming that for this problem I am not supposed to use it and there is a more straightforward way. And yes C[0,3] is the circle of radius 3 centred at 0.

Comment: Oh is that because complex log is not defined on the entire circle?

Comment: froggy, yes. Think about $t\mapsto e^{it}$. Intuitively, logarithm should read the exponent, but however you choose to define it, making a full circle (around the origin) will make logarithm jump by $2\pi i$, making it impossible to define continuous logarithm on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. This $2\pi i$ jump can be seen in Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: People often think $\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln|x|+C$ on reals, [but it's not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2218109) unless the $C$ has different values for $x>0,\,x<0$ (we say $C$ is _locally constant_). That's why $\int_{-2}^2\frac{dx}{x}$ is undefined. The complex equivalent is $C$ being phase-dependent. You can think of that as explaining why what you've tried doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the antiderivative

$$ \int \frac{3ie^{ix}}{6(3e^{ix} + 2)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{6}\log(3e^{ix} + 2) + \mathsf{C} \tag{*} $$

works only on an interval of the form $((2k-1)\pi, (2k+1)\pi)$, since the complex logarithm $\log(\cdot)$ has a branch cut along the negative real axis $(-\infty, 0]$ and the argument $3e^{ix} + 2$ passes through the cut whenever $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$.

For example, the graph below

[image: Comparosion]

compares the imaginary part of

$$ \color{rgb(94, 129, 181)}{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{3e^{it}}{6(3e^{it} + 2)} \, \mathrm{d}t} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \color{rgb(225, 156, 36)}{\left[ \frac{1}{6}\log(3e^{it} + 2) \right]_{t=0}^{t=x}} $$

as functions of $x$, and it is clear that the latter suffers from discontinuity introduced by the branch cut of $\log(\cdot)$. So, you have to account for this discontinuity if you want to utilize the antiderivative $\text{(*)}$, which will then give you the correct formula.

Answer (score 2):

You are integrating around a singularity ($z$ for which you end up dividing by zero) on $C[0,3]$, so this is where weirdness arises. Even though your startpoint and endpoint are the same, the singularity on the interior of your contour changes everything. Consider what happens when you take $$ \lim_{a \to 0} \int_{0}^{2\pi - a}\frac{3ie^{it}}{6(3e^{it}+2)}dt.$$